# Using author comments in posts

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, [questions with authoring comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83879/301-redirect-using-htaccess/83931#83931) surface, and whilst changes can greatly affect the difference in code, is an author comment really warranted in answer?

StackExchange's [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) link on the bottom of all SE sites, lists four things required to be done when republishing content:

> 1. **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network** in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. **Show the author names** for every question and answer
> 4. **Hyperlink each author name** directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

Whilst required republishing content; is an author comment like (`<!-- Author: Quill -->`) really required in the context of an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not required, but, is it a problem? No, it's not a problem either.

The author is possibly auto-inserted by an IDE or something. There's nothing wrong with that, but, again, there's no reason to remove it.

Whether there is attribution of authorship in an answer or not is independent of the licensing requirements of stack exchange.